# Bokeh plot displays nothing

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I wrote a Python program for plotting a candlestick graph based on financial data of Google. But I'm unable to get the graph (nothing is displayed). I think the problem is with the X coordinate i.e. `df.index`. Can someone help me to solve this issue?

```
from pandas_datareader import data
    import datetime
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

start=datetime.datetime(2016,3,1)
end=datetime.datetime(2016,3,10)

df=data.DataReader(name="GOOG",data_source="iex",start=start,end=end)


def inc_dec(c,o):
    if c>o:
        value="increase"
    elif c<o:
        value="decrease"
    else:
        value="Equal"
    return value

df["Status"]=[inc_dec(c,o) for c,o in zip(df.close,df.open)]
df["Middle"]=(df.close+df.open)/2
df["Height"]=abs(df.close-df.open)

p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime',width=1000, height=300)

p.title.text="Candlestick Chart"

p.segment(df.index,df.low,df.index,df.high,color="Black")

output_file("CS.html")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `df.index` is not a DateTimeIndex. It is a regular index that consists of strings:

```
df.index
```

> Index(['2016-03-01', '2016-03-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-03-04',
>   '2016-03-07',
>              '2016-03-08', '2016-03-09', '2016-03-10'],
>             dtype='object', name='date')

Thus, it is not what bokeh expects after you specify `x_axis_type='datetime'`. The solution is to convert the index to a DateTimeIndex like so:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index
```

> DatetimeIndex(['2016-03-01', '2016-03-02', '2016-03-03', '2016-03-04',
>                      '2016-03-07', '2016-03-08', '2016-03-09', '2016-03-10'],
>                     dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)

Then, you can properly display your plot!